# How to get rid of the year in my monthly plot (matplotlib)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've made a plot using python's matplotlib, which plots a dataframe of 1000 different sequences of daily values on a shared x axis. The x axis represents dates, from Jan 1, 1985 to Dec 31, 1985 but the year is irrelevant and only used to ensure data from all years is overlayed onto the same axis. When plotted with monthly axes, I am unable to avoid showing 1985 under the first "Jan" tick. This is ugly and annoying since none of the data are representative of 1985 (they are calculated results generated from synthetic input data).

[image]

How do I get rid of the year indicator on the first x axis tick? Can I define  date indices for the dataframe that don't contain a year somehow? Just **`mmm-dd`**? Even some tip to cover the year with a white box or something would be helpful.

Code used in defining the figure is below. I know it's ugly script, but it works for my needs....:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(11,8))

RSEs.plot(ax=axes[0,0], legend=False, title="Reservoir Elevation")
TBFs.plot(ax=axes[0,1], legend=False, title="Turbine Flow")
TSs.plot(ax=axes[1,0], legend=False, title="Total Spill")
OTs.plot(ax=axes[1,1], legend=False, title="Overtopping Flow")
l1=RLIMS[LimitCols[1]].plot(ax=axes[0,0], color="k", linestyle=":", legend=False)
l2=RLIMS[LimitCols[0]].plot(ax=axes[0,0], color="k", linestyle=":", legend=False)
l3=RLIMS[LimitCols[2]].plot(ax=axes[0,0], color="k", linestyle="--", legend=False)
l4=RLIMS[LimitCols[3]].plot(ax=axes[0,0], color="k", linestyle="--", legend=False)

#fig.autofmt_xdate()
axes[1,0].fmt_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter("%m")
axes[1,1].fmt_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter("%m")

axes[0,0].set_ylabel('Reservoir Elevation (m)', fontsize=14)
axes[0,1].set_ylabel('Turbine Flow (m$^3$/s)',  fontsize=14)
axes[1,0].set_ylabel('Gated Spill Release (m$^3$/s)', fontsize=14)
axes[1,1].set_ylabel('Free Overflow Spill (m$^3$/s)', fontsize=14)
axes[0,0].annotate('(a)', xy=(0.92, 0.9), xycoords='axes fraction', fontsize=14, horizontalalignment='top', verticalalignment='left')
axes[0,1].annotate('(b)', xy=(0.92, 0.9), xycoords='axes fraction', fontsize=14, horizontalalignment='top', verticalalignment='left')
axes[1,0].annotate('(c)', xy=(0.92, 0.9), xycoords='axes fraction', fontsize=14, horizontalalignment='top', verticalalignment='left')
axes[1,1].annotate('(d)', xy=(0.92, 0.9), xycoords='axes fraction', fontsize=14, 
horizontalalignment='top', verticalalignment='left')

axes[0,1].yaxis.set_label_coords(-0.115,0.5)
axes[1,0].yaxis.set_label_coords(-0.122,0.5)
```

The dates are defined as shown below and used to define index values for the dataframes containing the 1000 columns of different, synthetically driven, daily data.

```
dates=pd.DatetimeIndex(start="1985-01-01", end="1985-12-31", freq="D")
```

***EDIT***
Here are the contents of the data frames.... **`rse`**, **`tbf`**, **`ts`** and **`ot`** are simple arrays with dimensions 365 x 1000.

```
Cols=np.arange(1,1001)

RSEs=pd.DataFrame(rse, index=dates, columns=Cols)
TBFs=pd.DataFrame(tbf, index=dates, columns=Cols)
TSs=pd.DataFrame(ts, index=dates, columns=Cols)
OTs=pd.DataFrame(ot, index=dates, columns=Cols)
```

Comment: I fear that you might need to use matplotlib directly to plot, such that you can use custom formatters. Pandas is good at automatic labeling, but cannot be customized well/at all.

Comment: Please show content of *RSEs*, *TBFs*, *TSs*, *OTs* so we can see indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Just **`mmm-dd`**?

Best may tweak the proper settings via the X-axis **`DateFormatter( fmt, tz = None )`**, where `fmt` will set the *`strftime`*-formatting codes:

```
"%b-%d" # WARNING: %b produced content is locale-specific,
        #             so review a code in cases, where international deliveries
        #             may take place in the future
```

---

```
axes[i,j].xaxis.set_major_formatter( DateFormatter( '%b-%d' ) )
```

Comment: I get the error: NameError: name 'DateFormatter' is not defined when I add that to the code. Is there something I need to import? I also just want mmm in terms of the ticks on the x axis (no days, I am looking for a monthly plot showing multiple years of daily data)

Comment: **`import ...` ? absolutely**, `matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter( "%b" )` ( documentation is quite clear in these details + many additional tricks, just do not hesitate to read it )

Comment: It worked when I added "from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter". Thank you.